# Missing space after virtual box uninstall

Tags: virtual-machine

I had Oracle's VirtualBox software installed yesterday on my Windows 7 machine with a 20GB Ubuntu installation. I needed to free up some space so I uninstalled the virtualbox software. However I didn't notice any space free up on my hard drive.

Is there some way that the virtual box files still exist on my hard drive? I've done a search for .vdi files in my C:/ drive and that turned up nothing.

Comment: Which folder is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a utility like [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info/) to locate the large file(s).

Comment: I searched my C drive for large files already using the built in search...with nothing bigger than 250 MB

Comment: WinDirStat will highlight large folders as well.

Comment: it did the trick! Found my missing 20gb ;)

Comment: Where was it?  What path?

Comment: It was under a different users folder.